# Clustering and plotting in a vector space

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction

I have a vector-space-model. I want to cluster the embeddings (based on similarity) in this model,  but I have following dilemma / confusion:  Should I

1. **first cluster in the higher dimensional space** and then do dimensionality reduction to get a 2D plot I can display?

   or
2. **first do the dimensionality reduction** to a 2D space and then cluster on the 2D representations?

Answer (score 2):

I would say, (1) is *not* an option. Vector-space-model usually result in hundreds of features. Most clustering algorithms rely on the concept of distance between data points. With hundreds of features, you suffer from the [curse of dimensionality](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-curse-of-dimensionality-how-we-can-save-big-data-from-itself-d9fa0f872335). This makes most distance functions less effective (to say it politely).

(2) is also not so good, because reducing from hundreds of features to 2 will definitely introduce large distortions.

Thus, I would say, first try to reduce dimensionality to something reasonable (depending on number of data points you have). Then cluster.
Then think about possible ways to visualize in 2D.

Comment: I dont think curse of dimensionality is problem as essentially I have vector-space, which I have the basis for